# Search rows in Datatable with string a fast

Tags: c#, datatable

I need to select rows from with a string of IDs that are not the PK and int value x,
and datatable.select() takes to much time. Is there  faster way to select them.
this is my code:

```
String a = "Id1, id2, ...";

meldunng.Select("columnname1 = " + 2  " AND columnname2 IN (" + a  + ")")
```

If my question is confusing or I have worded it wrong please tell me.

Thanks in andvance

Comment: have you added index on columnname2? This will improve performance significantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `HashSet<string>` to improve performance and LINQ for the query:

```
var ids = new HashSet<string>(new[] {"Id1", "id2", "id3"}, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase); // i guess you want to ignore the case
var matchingRows = meldunng.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<int>("columnname1") == 2 && ids.Contains(row.Field<string>("columnname2")));
```

Note that this is just the LINQ query and you need to "materialize" it to something, for example a `DataRow[]`:

```
DataRow[] resultRows = matchingRows.ToArray();
```